# Did Muhammad say that black seeds can cure any disease?

Tags: hadith, prophet-muhammad, sick

Did the the prophet of Islam say that black seeds can cures diseases?

Comment: That is not the reason the question was closed on Skeptics.StackExchange. This was not even the question asked.

Comment: It's a slightly different question. Still it's related. Because if Muhammad truly said that and it's written in one of the most reliable hadiths (=gospel in christianity), then it is a very notable claim.

Comment: I did mention if I asked in skeptic stackexchange whether the statement is true or not. I asked in islam stackexchange if muhammad really said it at all because they are the one that know what hadiths are

Comment: be polite when you call a prophet's name. include the good title, such as Prophet or Nabi.

Answer (score 5):

All Praise to Allah Subhanahu wa Taala and blessings of Him be on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His family and companions,

Yeah it is true,

> Abu Hurairah narrated that the Messenger of Allah (s.a.w) said: "Use
>   this black seed. For indeed it contains a cure for every disease
>   except As-Sam" And As-Sam is death.(Tirmidhi)

And

> Abu Hurairah narrated that he heard the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) say: “In
>   black seed there is healing for every disease, except the Sam.” "Sam
>   means death. And black seed is Shuwniz."(Ibn Majah)

Allah Swt and His Messenger knows best.

Comment: what language is asam?

Comment: @JimThio Its in Arabic.

Comment: so, arabic words for death is sam? And Muhammad must be talking to the other guy in arabic. So why translate the whole sentences except "sam"?

Comment: Word "Sam" has some different meanings too.

Comment: like what? such as?

Comment: @JimThio see this http://www.almaany.com/en/dict/ar-en/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%91%D9%8E%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%8E/

Comment: "Sam" actually refers to the poison , Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him said that it has healing for every disease except for the "poison" and poison would lead to the death.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are many hadiths that say this. Narrated Abu Huraira:

> I heard Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) saying, "There is healing in black cumin
> for all diseases except death." Reference: Sahih al-Bukhari 5688

---

> Abu Hurairah narrated that the Messenger of Allah (s.a.w) said: "Use
> this black seed. For indeed it contains a cure for every disease
> except As-Sam" And As-Sam is death.
>
> Grade: Sahih, Reference: Tirmidhi, Vol. 4, Book 2, Hadith 2041

---

> It was narrated that ‘Uthman bin ‘Abdul-Malik said: “I heard Salim bin
> ‘Abdullah narrating from his father that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ)
> said: ‘You should eat this black seed, for in it there is healing from
> every disease, except the Sam (death).’” -- [Source](http://sunnah.com/urn/1274930)

---

> Narrated Khalid bin Sad: We went out and Ghalib bin Abjar was
> accompanying us. He fell ill on the way and when we arrived at Medina
> he was still sick. Ibn Abi 'Atiq came to visit him and said to us,
> "Treat him with black cumin. Take five or seven seeds and crush them
> (mix the powder with oil) and drop the resulting mixture into both
> nostrils, for `Aisha has narrated to me that she heard the Prophet (ﷺ)
> saying, 'This black cumin is healing for all diseases except As-Sam.'
> Aisha said, 'What is As-Sam?' He said, 'Death."
>
> Reference: Sahih al-Bukhari 5687

P.S There is, in fact, some scientific evidence to suggest that black seed might help boost the immune system and thereby acts as a remedy for all diseases. [WebMD](http://www.webmd.com/vitamins-supplements/ingredientmono-901-black%20seed.aspx?activeingredientid=901&activeingredientname=black%20seed) writes regarding the use of black seed for medical purposes:

> Today, black seed is used for treating digestive tract conditions
> including gas, colic, diarrhea, dysentery, constipation, and
> hemorrhoids. It is also used for respiratory conditions including
> asthma, allergies, cough, bronchitis, emphysema, flu, swine flu, and
> congestion.
>
> Other uses include lowering blood pressure, lowering cholesterol
> levels, treating cancer, and boosting the immune system.
>
> ...There is some scientific evidence to suggest that black seed might
> help boost the immune system, fight cancer, prevent pregnancy, and
> lessen allergic reactions by acting as an antihistamine...