# What are the benefits of using olive oil in Islam?

Tags: quran, hadith

The Prophet Muhammad (SAWS) said:

> 'Eat olive oil and rub it on your skin, for it comes from a blessed tree.'
>
> (Narrated by Ahmad and Al-Tirmidhi)

In Surah Tin, the first line says:

> 'By the fig and the olive'. ([95:1](https://quran.com/95))

This indicates an oath is sworn by these fruit meaning it is blessed and has good qualities to be able to swear by it.

> Zaitoon(Olives) are mentioned in numerous places in the Quran  (141-M-AlInaam-6), (99-K-AlInaam-6), (11-K-AlNahl-16), (AlNoor-35), (Moominoon).

All of this state that the olive tree is blessed. When the Prophet Muhammad said to eat it and put it on our skin, it must have a reason or benefit to us. What are those?

I'm just wondering as I have been brought up using olive oil every time I had a shower and recently found out it has Islamic significance so I was just wondering this is why I might have had to use olive oil after having a shower from the day I was born.

I am looking for Islamic benefits.

Comment: Are you asking about health benefits? That should be off-topic here, probably try [health.se] for that. If that's not what you're asking, can you clarify what you're looking for?

Comment: @G.Bach I'm asking for Islamic benefits.

Comment: What do you mean with islamic benefit?

Comment: I mean do you get thawab (reward) and how much and benefits like curing illnesses in Islam.